# Google VM cannot receive response via REST API

Tags: python, rest, google-cloud-vm

I have a Google VM and would like to run the below python code to get results, however I get an error. If I type the url in the browser I get the response that tells me the error is on my side.
Here I put the code as well as the error I get. I would really appreciate any help.

```
import requests
# response = requests.get("http://palmetto.aksw.org/palmetto-webapp/service/cp?words=cake%20apple%20banana%20cherry%20chocolate")
response = requests.get("http://palmetto.aksw.org/palmetto-webapp/service/calculate?coherence=cp&words=cake%20apple%20banana%20cherry%20chocolate")
```

The error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py:174, in HTTPConnection._new_conn(self)
    173 try:
--> 174     conn = connection.create_connection(
    175         (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
    176     )
    178 except SocketTimeout:

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py:95, in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     94 if err is not None:
---> 95     raise err
     97 raise socket.error("getaddrinfo returns an empty list")

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py:85, in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     84     sock.bind(source_address)
---> 85 sock.connect(sa)
     86 return sock

OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:703, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    702 # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 703 httplib_response = self._make_request(
    704     conn,
    705     method,
    706     url,
    707     timeout=timeout_obj,
    708     body=body,
    709     headers=headers,
    710     chunked=chunked,
    711 )
    713 # If we're going to release the connection in ``finally:``, then
    714 # the response doesn't need to know about the connection. Otherwise
    715 # it will also try to release it and we'll have a double-release
    716 # mess.

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:398, in HTTPConnectionPool._make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    397     else:
--> 398         conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
    400 # We are swallowing BrokenPipeError (errno.EPIPE) since the server is
    401 # legitimately able to close the connection after sending a valid response.
    402 # With this behaviour, the received response is still readable.

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py:239, in HTTPConnection.request(self, method, url, body, headers)
    238     headers["User-Agent"] = _get_default_user_agent()
--> 239 super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py:1240, in HTTPConnection.request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1239 """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1240 self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py:1286, in HTTPConnection._send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1285     body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1286 self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py:1235, in HTTPConnection.endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1234     raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1235 self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py:1006, in HTTPConnection._send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1005 del self._buffer[:]
-> 1006 self.send(msg)
   1008 if message_body is not None:
   1009 
   1010     # create a consistent interface to message_body

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py:946, in HTTPConnection.send(self, data)
    945 if self.auto_open:
--> 946     self.connect()
    947 else:

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py:205, in HTTPConnection.connect(self)
    204 def connect(self):
--> 205     conn = self._new_conn()
    206     self._prepare_conn(conn)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py:186, in HTTPConnection._new_conn(self)
    185 except SocketError as e:
--> 186     raise NewConnectionError(
    187         self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
    188     )
    190 return conn

NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f847d936190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py:489, in HTTPAdapter.send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    488 if not chunked:
--> 489     resp = conn.urlopen(
    490         method=request.method,
    491         url=url,
    492         body=request.body,
    493         headers=request.headers,
    494         redirect=False,
    495         assert_same_host=False,
    496         preload_content=False,
    497         decode_content=False,
    498         retries=self.max_retries,
    499         timeout=timeout,
    500     )
    502 # Send the request.
    503 else:

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:787, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    785     e = ProtocolError("Connection aborted.", e)
--> 787 retries = retries.increment(
    788     method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
    789 )
    790 retries.sleep()

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py:592, in Retry.increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    591 if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 592     raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    594 log.debug("Incremented Retry for (url='%s'): %r", url, new_retry)

MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='palmetto.aksw.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /palmetto-webapp/service/calculate?coherence=cp&words=cake%20apple%20banana%20cherry%20chocolate (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f847d936190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [7], line 3
      1 import requests
      2 # response = requests.get("http://palmetto.aksw.org/palmetto-webapp/service/cp?words=cake%20apple%20banana%20cherry%20chocolate")
----> 3 response = requests.get("http://palmetto.aksw.org/palmetto-webapp/service/calculate?coherence=cp&words=cake%20apple%20banana%20cherry%20chocolate")
      4 print(response.text)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py:73, in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     62 def get(url, params=None, **kwargs):
     63     r"""Sends a GET request.
     64 
     65     :param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
   (...)
     70     :rtype: requests.Response
     71     """
---> 73     return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py:59, in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     55 # By using the 'with' statement we are sure the session is closed, thus we
     56 # avoid leaving sockets open which can trigger a ResourceWarning in some
     57 # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     58 with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 59     return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:587, in Session.request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    582 send_kwargs = {
    583     "timeout": timeout,
    584     "allow_redirects": allow_redirects,
    585 }
    586 send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 587 resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    589 return resp

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:701, in Session.send(self, request, **kwargs)
    698 start = preferred_clock()
    700 # Send the request
--> 701 r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    703 # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)
    704 elapsed = preferred_clock() - start

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py:565, in HTTPAdapter.send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    561     if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
    562         # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
    563         raise SSLError(e, request=request)
--> 565     raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    567 except ClosedPoolError as e:
    568     raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='palmetto.aksw.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /palmetto-webapp/service/calculate?coherence=cp&words=cake%20apple%20banana%20cherry%20chocolate (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f847d936190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable'))
```

As I checked the HTTPS and HTTP both are allowed on the setting of the VM. I think I need to change a setting in the VM network section but I do not know what change(s) should be done.

Comment: Works fine for me. Did you give it enough time to start up?

Comment: If it is a get request, you can just go to the website and see the response as well (unless it needs header information/cookies)